# How to resize an iframe and div layed-out side by side like jsbin or jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I have a div placed beside an iframe. I want to resize the iframe/div with a toggler as shown in the image. Although, I tried using the following:

http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

http://methvin.com/splitter/

they seem to work fine only when two divs are placed side by side. However, when I place 1 div on the left and one iframe on the right, they are all acting weird while trying to resize. I tried putting the iframe inside a div as well, but there is something awkward about it as well.

To make things easier to understand, I was basically looking for something like http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net features. They both seem to have iframes (the 'result' area) that can be resized perfectly.

I was looking for a solution using HTML, CSS/CSS3, JavaScript, JQuery, JQuery UI only. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: No follow up after my post?

Comment: Sorry...about that... Thank you for the answer. However, I have decided to use the following library .... http://www.jqwidgets.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the best way I know, but it could possibly be a start.  I have done no research on this, just tried my hand based on some simple reasoning.  The big problem I see is getting the mouse position over an iframe so I solved that by altering the z-index of the iframe and an overlay div accordingly.  Not tested cross browser, just chrome.  Anyway, maybe something here that could help.  I recommend copy paste this and run it locally.  It is broken up into two different files.

First File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #main_wrapper{
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        width:810px;
        height:800px;
    }
    #left_wrapper{
        background-color: yellow;       
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        width:400px;
        height:800px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #right_wrapper{
        background-color: blue; 
        position:relative;
        float:right;
        width:400px;
        height:800px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #middle_bar{
        background-color: black;        
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        width:10px;
        height:800px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #middle_bar:hover{
        cursor:move;
    }
    #overlay_div{
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: rgba(10,10,10,.1);
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #my_iframe{
        z-index: 2;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    starting_mouse_pos = 0; 
    mouse_down = false;

    $('#middle_bar').on('mousedown', function(event){                           
        starting_mouse_pos = event.pageX;
        mouse_down = true;      
        $('#overlay_div').css('z-index', '2');
        $('#my_iframe').css('z-index', '1');
    });
    $('#main_wrapper').on('mouseup', function(){
        mouse_down = false;
        $('#overlay_div').css('z-index', '1');
        $('#my_iframe').css('z-index', '2');
    });
    $('#main_wrapper').on('mousemove', function(event){     
        if(mouse_down){
            var ending_mouse_pos = event.pageX;             
            update_the_sizes(ending_mouse_pos);             
            starting_mouse_pos = ending_mouse_pos;
        }       
    });
    function update_the_sizes(ending_mouse_pos){
        var length_of_move = starting_mouse_pos - ending_mouse_pos;
        $('#left_wrapper').css('width', '-='+length_of_move);
        $('#right_wrapper').css('width', '+='+length_of_move);
        $('#my_iframe').css('width', '+='+length_of_move);      
    }   
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main_wrapper">
    <div id="left_wrapper"></div>
    <div id="middle_bar"></div>
    <div id="right_wrapper">
        <div id="overlay_div"></div>
        <iframe id="my_iframe" width="400px" height="800px" src="myIframe.html" seamless></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Second File (myIframe.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #main_wrapper{
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-color: purple;
    }
    body{
        background-color: green;
    }

</style>

<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main_wrapper"> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```